# how do i use background Worker in this for loop c#

Tags: c#, windows, backgroundworker

How do I use a background worker in this for loop?

```
int tmax = 10;
int xmax = newbitmap.Width;
int ymax = newbitmap.Height;
for (int t = 0; t <= tmax; t += 1)
{
  for (int x = 0; x < xmax; x++)
  {
    for (int y = 0; y < ymax; y++)
    {
      if ((x / xmax) > (t / tmax))
      {
        Color originalco = newbitmap2.GetPixel(x, y);
        outp.SetPixel(x, y, originalco);
      }
      else
      {
        Color originalco3 = newbitmap.GetPixel(x, y); ;
        outp.SetPixel(x, y, originalco3);
      }

    }

    pictureBox1.Image = outp;
  }
}
```

This loop is a wipe transition from right to left, but it doesn't display the transition.

Comment: You want your background worker to process that code? Then just put it inside of the workers `DoWork` method and pass in any objects it might need via `worker.RunWorkerAsync(object)`...

Answer (score 3):

That because the backgroundWorker works in a different thread. You can use `backgroundworker.ReportProgress(0, outp)`

So:
You need to register to the event `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` from the events window in Vistual Studio, or with this line:

```
backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
```

The method:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var outp = (Bitmap)e.UserState;
        prictureBox.Image = outp;
    }
```

Your code sould be then:

```
        int tmax = 10;
        int xmax = newbitmap.Width;
        int ymax = newbitmap.Height;
        for (int t = 0; t <= tmax; t += 1)
        {

            for (int x = 0; x < xmax; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < ymax; y++)
                {
                    if ((x / xmax) > (t / tmax))
                    {
                        Color originalco = newbitmap2.GetPixel(x, y);
                        outp.SetPixel(x, y, originalco);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Color originalco3 = newbitmap.GetPixel(x, y); ;
                        outp.SetPixel(x, y, originalco3);
                    }

                }

                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(t, outp);

            }
        }
```

Comment: This BackgroundWorker states that it doesn't report progress. Modify WorkerReportsProgress to state that it does report progress.

Comment: @OmarAl-hamawi From the properties winodw, change property BackgroundWorkerReportsProgress to `true`.

Comment: @OmarAl-hamawi Still throwing exception or not view image on UI?

Comment: I've sent to your account on facebook please check it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use direct pixel manipulation as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx

Then, you should use an array as lookup for all your threads which line has already been drawn and which hasn't. The threads look for a new line in this array and then draw it. But remember to lock the lookup array!

Answer (score 1):

Your Do work method would look something like this: -

```
private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     Bitmap newbitmap = (Bitmap)e.Argument;

     int tmax = 10;
     int xmax = newbitmap.Width;
     int ymax = newbitmap.Height;
     for (int t = 0; t <= tmax; t += 1)
     {

         for (int x = 0; x < xmax; x++)
         {
              for (int y = 0; y < ymax; y++)
              {
                   if ((x / xmax) > (t / tmax))
                   {
                       Color originalco = newbitmap2.GetPixel(x, y);
                       outp.SetPixel(x, y, originalco);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       Color originalco3 = newbitmap.GetPixel(x, y); ;
                       outp.SetPixel(x, y, originalco3);
                   }

               }
               pictureBox1.Image = outp;
         }
      }
      bgWorker.ReportProgress(0,outp);
}
```

Then when your worker reports progress, it would raise the following event where you can safely update the UI:

```
private void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //UPDATE YOUR UI HERE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ReportProgress` method of Background Worker to update the UI.

[Read more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress.aspx_)